# How do I loop through this until I am out of arrows

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I think I am pretty far off, but I am trying to create a scenario where on click of id 12a, I want to alert user to enter a number and keep entering a number until they've used up 5 arrows. Where did I go wrong?

```
var arrows = 5;
alert('You have ' + arrows + ' arrows!');
var shot    = prompt('How many arrows would you like to shoot?', '1');
var shotten  = parseInt(shot);

$('#12a').click(function(){
if(isNaN(shotten)){
    alert('You must enter a valid number of arrows!');
} else if(shotten > arrows){
    alert('Sorry, but there are only ' + arrows + ' arrows.  You can not shoot ' + shotten + ' arrows!');
} else if(shotten < 0){
    alert('Sorry, but you cannot shoot less than 0 arrows!');
} else {
    arrows -= shotten;
    alert('Now there are only ' + arrows + ' arrows!');
} 
});



  <p>There's a half-elf running at you. You can shoot him with your arrows if you'd like. </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="12a" id="12a" value="Let's do it.">
  </p>
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue  ?

Comment: First off, it's not launching when I click the id.

Comment: its working fine here , https://jsfiddle.net/yd8tz438/

Comment: Thanks for showing me that. For some reason, it's not working for me. I have a test.html file with a link to jquery, the arrow scripts, and the HTML. But it won't work when I click the button.

Comment: Check your browser console for any potential js errors. I am suspecting missing jquery library

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Can you tell me how make it so that once it gets down to 0, then #choiceW shows? I tried adding another if statement like: if (arrows == 0) {$('choiceW').show(); but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'd selector is wrong , try this way `$('#choiceW').show();`

Comment: Ahhh! That was terrible of me. That's what I get for trying to do this at work. Thanks so much.

Comment: No probs,happens all the time.I'll post the answer below,you can close the question

Comment: Now let's close this question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple things a developer should watch out for when working with JavaScript/webpage.

- if the page doesn't work the way you intend to then first check your browser console for potential issues.
- usual errors would be because of some library's missing or failed to load eg jQuery etc.,
- JS syntax errors
- finally logical errors.